# Added Jquery reference to masterpage but not propagating to site pages

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2013

I added a JQuery reference to my master page and it worked like a charm for the parts on the home page. But when I go to a subsite, the JQuery part no longer works. I tried to add a reference to the page itself but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: Please give more information. Is there an error in the Console?

Answer (score 0):

When you say, "I Tried to add a reference to the page itself...," I think you mean your sub-pages are trying to point to the main page and reference the JQuery link there. If so, that doesn't work (as you have found). Add a link for JQuery in the  area of each page:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

That is assuming you are pointing to an online file, at Google (or jquery.com), because it is often cached in user browsers because it is so ubiquitous. If you have downloaded the files and are including file paths from your sub-pages, make sure the pathnames are correct. If the index (main page) and the sub-pages are in the same directory, the path should be the same, but verify they are (if that is how you did it).

Hope that helps.

Comment: where on the page do i add it. it seems to get erased every time i save it in SharePoint designer?